# Custom fromJS immutablejs issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I created a custom fromJS function so that when I convert objects over to Immutable objects then the result would only contain OrderedSets and Maps (instead of Lists and Maps).

This has worked perfectly fine except for in the following case where a key in the object is called "length". Any ideas how to fix the issue at hand?

```
var imm = require("immutable")

function fromJS(js) {
    return typeof js !== 'object' || js === null ? js :
        Array.isArray(js) ? 
            imm.Seq(js).map(fromJS).toOrderedSet() :
            imm.Seq(js).map(fromJS).toMap();
}

var output = fromJS({
    measurements: {
        length: 10,
        weight: 30
    }
}).toJS();

// output is :
{
    measurements: {
        0: undefined,
        1: undefined
        ....
        32: undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got worked by changing the property `length` to `mLength`.

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kidufow/edit?js,console)

ImmutableJS looks for `length` property to check whether the given value is [array-like](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/utils/isArrayLike.js#L11) object or not.

Since your `measurements` object has a property `length`, it considers that this object is an `array-like` object and continues the `Seq` construction based on `array-like` type, here the problem starts.

---

To confirm this, [here](http://jsbin.com/zawixoj/edit?js,console) is the jsbin which outputs the `Map` with no.of time given in the length property of the `measurements` object.